# comparing columns form 2 tabs for matches and populate a cell with a value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 tabs (tab1 and tab2) in one worksheet.  Each tab has a column "AP" which has unique a number for each row.  I am wanting to use a number in first cell of column AP in tab1 and compare it to all the cells in the AP column of tab2.  When there is a match I want to take the value in column B of tab2 and copy it into the cell of column AM of tab1.

As you probably can tell i am not very good with excel so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look for `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.